# How to create a light border for an app icon

Tags: icon, iphone

This is a fine piece of iPhone app icon:

[image]

I'm wondering how they created the fine texture along with the slight 'glow' on the edges:

[image]

I suppose the texture is made by a semi-transparent layer on top of the red background, but how did they do the light red glow on the border of the icon?

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, this can be done by using stroke.

Left click on layers and open blending option

```
Blending option > Stroke
```

and then select color according to need.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, two options come to mind.

- Use the inner glow effect
- Add another fill and apply a transform effect to scale it in from the edges.